# How to extract lines from a column separated by empty lines?

Tags: unix, text-processing

I have a large file of tokenized sentences. Different sentences are separated from each other by empty lines. Input file is basically just a one large column.

I'd like to transpose the single column in a way that each unique sentence gets its own line.

Input:

```
Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence1

Sentence2
Sentence2
Sentence2

...

SentenceN
```

Desired output would be this:

```
Sentence1 Sentence1 Sentence1 Sentence1
Sentence2 Sentence2 Sentence2
...
```

I've been looking to grep, awk, sed and tr but I'm struggling with the correct syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose your record and field separators sensibly it is straightforward with `awk`:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS= FS="\n" OFS=" " infile
```

Output:

```
Sentence1 Sentence1 Sentence1 Sentence1
Sentence2 Sentence2 Sentence2
...
SentenceN
```

#### Explanation

- `RS=` sets the record separator to "empty line".
- `FS="\n"` sets the field separator to new-line.
- `OFS=" "` sets the output separator to space.
- `$1=$1` reevaluates the input and splits it according to `FS`. This also evaluates to true and thus outputs the input with `OFS` as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Dead easy with `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n\n";

while ( <DATA> ) {
   s/\n/ /g;
   print;
   print "\n";
}

__DATA__
Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence1
Sentence1

Sentence2
Sentence2
Sentence2
```

Or one-liner-ified:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I certainly got closer to my goal but the sentences are in now in a one single line. My aim is to get one sentence into its own line.

Comment: @seppo: it needs a `-l` (dash-ell) to add new-lines after records. In addition you might want to add `$\ = "\n"` after the substitution command to reduce spacing between records.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution

```
awk '{ if($1~"^$") {print a;a="";} else a=a" "$0;} END {print a}' test.txt
```